# Associative rings with "big" commutative subrings

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $A$ be an associative ring and $R\subset A$ be a commutative subring. Suppose that every element of $A$ has the form $urv$ where $r\in R$ and $u, v\in A^*$ are invertible. A basic example is $A=M_n(k)$ and $R\subset A$ is a subring of diagonal matrices.

It seems that in this situation many algebraic properties of $A$ can be extracted from some properties of $R$. For example, if $A$ is commutative then $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Spec}R$. What is known about rings $A$ admitting such subring? It is a reference request question.

Comment: I'm assuming it is implicit your rings are unital?

Comment: @Wojowu definitely. Otherwise being invertible does not make sense.

Comment: Well, in a possibly non-unital ring one can say $a$ is invertible if there exists $b$ satisfying $abx=bax=xab=xba=x$ for all $x$; then $b$ is unique and of course if the ring is unital $b$ is the inverse. In any case it sounds natural to assume the ring unital in the question.